# How can i find NSString having atlease one charater in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, special-characters

Am working on Message based iPhone app. I have to pass numbers to Webservice if the  k like `a-z and A-Z` i have alert the user to omit the letters from the numbers. How can i find `NSString value having a-z and A-Z letters` in it? Anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean you want to detect if a NSString contains letters only (a-zA-Z) or not?

Comment: Yes i want to detect only (a-zA-Z) from NSString values. Thank you.

Comment: In my answer you are searching for 10 Numbers.. if other than that you would get NO value returned.. which would serve your purpose

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I have solved the issue. Thanks once again to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString * regexName = @"[a-zA-Z] * ";

```
NSString *testString = @"your string";

NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",regexName];

if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:testString]) {
    NSLog(@"true");        
}
```

else{NSLog"string contains numbers or special characters"  ;}

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if there is ANY character in your string use something like this:

```
if ([yourString length] > 0) {
    // nice feature here is, this will also work when yourString is nil! :D
}
```

**---**

If you want to do a more complex check you will have to use [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Use [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class like this:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[A-Za-z]+$" options:0] error:NULL];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:yourString
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
if (numberOfMatches > 0) {
    // yourString does only consist of multiple letters
}
```

`^[a-zA-Z]+$` matches only strings that consist of one or more letters only (`^` and `$` mark the begin and end of a string respectively). `^[0-9]+$` matches numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

That should be it :)

```
NSCharacterSet *alphaSet = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
BOOL valid = [[yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:alphaSet] isEqualToString:@""];
```

It removes all the letters from your string, if there is anything left, then `valid` is `NO`.

Hope that helps ! :)

Comment: Or, if you want numbers only (regardless of what else is there), you can use `[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]`.

Comment: @PhillipMills If you want to check if the string contains numbers only and nothing but numbers, you can use `[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]` (without invertedSet). In my code, I am trimming all the letters I want and compare it with an empty string. :)

Comment: My comment was meant to say that, instead of just removing letters, it might be safer to remove anything "non-digit" if the original statement "I have to pass numbers" is taken literally.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
NSCharacterSet *alphabetSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet];

if ([yourString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:alphabetSet].location == NSNotFound) {
  if(yourString.length >= 1)
  {
    // has aleast one character
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From What I understand you want phone Numbers to be entered

First of all you can set the keypad as UIKeyboardTypePhonePad or UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad for the UITextView you are adding the numbers to.

**OR**

Pass the text to this function

```
-(BOOL) checkForPhoneNumber:(NSString *) string
{
    NSPredicate *confidenceTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",NUMBER_REGEX]; 
    return [confidenceTest evaluateWithObject:string]?YES:NO;
}
```

where

```
#define NUMBER_REGEX @"^[0-9]10?$"
```